# javascript P5 function creates endless loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, p5.js

I can't for the life of me work out how to reset the function createAliens below so I can begin a new game - I'm basically looking for a way to clear the sprites off the canvas so I can reset the game.

Any help would be seriously appreciated :)

```js
const BORDER = 60;
const SPEED = 3;

let score = 0;

let numAliens = 3;
let alienSpeed = 5;
let aliensArray = [];

let ship; 
let laser;
let lasers = [];

function preload() {
    
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(1000, 700);

    aliens = new Group();
    ships = new Group();
    lasers = new Group();

    createAliens(numAliens);

    ship = createSprite(width/2, height/1.15, 40, 60); 
    ship.setCollider('rectangle', 0, 0, 40, 60); 
    ships.add(ship); 
}

function draw() {
    background(0);
    
    if(aliens == 0) {
        createAliens(numAliens + 2);
    }

    aliens.bounce(aliens); // p5 game methods - collision etc using callbacks
    aliens.overlap(lasers, scoreTotal);
    aliens.collide(lasers, die);
    ship.bounce(aliens, reset);

    keyPressed();
    drawSprites();    

    for (let i = 0; i < allSprites.length; i++) { // game borderless
        let all = allSprites[i];
            if (all.position.x < - BORDER) {
                all.position.x = width + BORDER;
            }
            if (all.position.x > width + BORDER) {
                all.position.x = - BORDER;
            }            
            if (all.position.y < - BORDER) {
                all.position.y = height + BORDER;
            }            
            if (all.position.y > height + BORDER) {
                all.position.y = - BORDER;
            }            
    }    
}

function createAliens(numAliens) { // spawn some aliens
    for (let j = 0; j < numAliens; j++) {
        alien = createSprite(random(width), 0, 50, 60);
        alien.shapeColor = color('red');
        alien.setSpeed(random(0.3, alienSpeed), random(45, 150));        
        
        aliensArray.push(alien); 
        aliens.add(alien); 
    }    
}

function die(alien) { // kill the alien
    alien.remove(); 
}

function scoreTotal() { 
    score += 10;    
}
 
function reset() {
    console.log('RESET FIRING');    
}

function keyPressed() {
    if (keyDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
        ship.setSpeed(SPEED, 180);        
        ship.friction = 0.01;
    }
    else if (keyDown(RIGHT_ARROW)) {
        ship.setSpeed(SPEED, 0);        
        ship.friction = 0.01;
    }
    else if (keyDown(UP_ARROW)) {
        ship.setSpeed(SPEED, 270);
        ship.friction = 0.01;
    }
    else if (keyDown(DOWN_ARROW)) {        
        ship.setSpeed(SPEED, 90);
        ship.friction = 0.01;
    }
    if(keyWentDown(' '))  {
        let laser = createSprite(ship.position.x, ship.position.y, 5, 5);
        laser.setSpeed(10, 270);
        laser.shapeColor = color('red');        
        laser.life = 30; 
        lasers.add(laser);        
    }
}
```

I have got the aliens spawning with the simple conditional logic:

```js
if(aliens == 0) {
        createAliens(numAliens + 2);
    }
```

Comment: i neglected to mention that i'm using the p5.play library...

Comment: Without having gone through all the code: what does a reset look like in your use case, how is it going to get triggered? Or is there already code in place meant to fulfill this functionality, which just isn't working? I'm asking because your `draw` function (which loops constantly) reacts to there being `0` aliens.

Comment: And `createAliens` cannot really be "reset" because it is meant to create aliens. Are you asking how to rewrite your code so the `createAliens` function is not automatically run all the time? (Still, a trigger for running/not running it is needed.)

Comment: Hi Kay, that sounds great, I'm a bit stymied :)